# NGINX proxy_pass not routing correctly by dns

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I was trying to run the following configuration in nginx:
Here is my test.conf file

```
map $environment $backend {
    ~^testing1[1-9]|testing1[0-4]    http://google.com;
    ~^testing1[5-9][1-8]         http://gmail.com;
    ~^testing10[1-8]            http://example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<environment>testing[1-9]|testing1[0-4]|testing[5-9][1-8]|testing10[1-8])-(?<service_name>[^.]+)\.example\.com$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $backend;
    }
}
```

The main idea behind it was, that when getting request by *testing8-service.example.com* (I have A record with **service.example.com* to my NGINX) it would be redirected to *google.com*, however right now it opens default NGINX page. Could someone please help me to determine what I have done wrongly, any help or advices are appreciated

While for nginx.conf I use default config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the `server` block appears.